# How to refer to the object on which an action was performed

Tags: java, swing

I created an `ArrayList` of `JButton`s using a `for` loop, so I don't have a specific name for each object. In the `actionPerformed()` method, I want to get the index of the button that was just pressed. Using the `this` keyword, it refers to the overall class this is defined in, not the object that was pressed.

```java
public class Game implements ActionListener
{   
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        int temp = this.buttons.indexOf(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are several ways to get the index of the button that was pressed. The best way depends on what you want to do with that index. Does each button (in the list) perform a different action depending on the index of that button? I believe I can offer you an alternative solution to that which you are trying to implement now. Can you provide some background as to why you are using a list of buttons? Does each button have text? Is it the same text for each button? Do the buttons have an icon? Are the icons the same for each button?

Comment: Of-course, simplest solution would be (in method `actionPerformed`): `buttons.indexOf(event.getSource()))` where `buttons` is your `ArrayList` of buttons and `event` is the [`actionPerformed`] method parameter, which is an instance of class `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

The actionPerformed() method has the [ActionEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html) as parameter.
Use the getSource() method to find out which object fired the event.

With that, your ActionListener can look like this (I assume you attach this ActionListener only to JButtons):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton pressedButton = (JButton)e.getSource();

    // do whatever you need to do with that button
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is first solution. In this case you can use the internal ActionEvent getSource() methods

```
private static List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
static class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int buttonIndex = buttons.indexOf(e.getSource());
        JButton pressedButton = buttons.get(buttonIndex);
        // buttonIndex and pressedButton. You can do whatever you want
        System.out.println(buttonIndex); // Just for testing
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Buttons");

    // set frame site
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setText(Integer.valueOf(i).toString());// Just to display for testing
        MyButtonListener myListener = new MyButtonListener();
        btn.addActionListener(myListener);
        buttons.add(btn);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(btn);
    }
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

==================================================

This is second solution. This time you set the index on the creation of the Button Listener (inside the constructor). Here you use class parameter which will memorize which was the button index. Then when you are using it and it will know already which is the button.

```
private static List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
static class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    int buttonIndex;
    public MyButtonListener(int i) {
        buttonIndex = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton pressedButton = buttons.get(buttonIndex);
        //... Work here with pressedButton or buttonIndex  
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        MyButtonListener myListener = new MyButtonListener(i); //Here set the index in the constructor
        btn.addActionListener(myListener);
        buttons.add(btn);
    }

}
```

Best of luck to all!